# Groupby two columns and take average categorical count in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I would like to Groupby two columns and take average categorical count in Python

**(We see that NY holds 3 apples, WA holds 4 cherries and TX holds 3 bbq for the date of 2/1/22 - now we take the average for those 3 containers.)**

**Data**

```
CONTAINER   CLOUDS   DATE
NY          apple    2/1/2022
NY          apple    2/1/2022
NY          apple    2/1/2022
WA          cherries 2/1/2022
WA          cherries 2/1/2022
WA          cherries 2/1/2022
WA          cherries 2/1/2022
TX          bbq      2/1/2022
TX          bbq      2/1/2022
TX          bbq      2/1/2022
TX          bbq      3/1/2022
TX          bbq      3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
AVG CLOUDS PER CONTAINER:  ~3.333
```

**Doing**

```
df = df.groupby('CONTAINER', 'DATE') \
.agg({'CLOUDS':'size', 'CLOUDS':'mean'}) \
.reset_index()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can perform your first groupby on `'CONTAINER','DATE'` and get the `size` of each category, then perform another groupby on the `'DATE'` alone and calculate the mean:

```
df.groupby(['CONTAINER','DATE']).agg({'CLOUDS':'size'}).reset_index().groupby('DATE').agg({'CLOUDS':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
       DATE    CLOUDS
0  2/1/2022  3.333333
1  3/1/2022  2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Is there documentation on this, I tried researching pandas and did not see this

Comment: I don't think there is any particular documentation for performing two groupby operations– i just figured this out by trial and error (and looking the results of your initial groupby)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unclear about what you want. If you are only interested in container on 2/1/2022:

```py
# Measure container size on 2/1/2022 only
cond = df["DATE"] == "2/1/2022"
output = df[cond].groupby("CONTAINER").size()

# Take the average of all containers' sizes
output["AVG"] = output.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Is there documentation on this, I tried researching pandas and did not see this